# Transferring HTML data between pages

Tags: html

Been really stressed out for a while, as I'm very new to coding and can't figure out how to transfer some paragraph data across pages. 
Here is my code on my first page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    <h1>z</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>test</p>
    <p id="goalPage"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var t = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1);
    if (t === 1) {document.getElementById("goalPage").innerHTML = "Your goal page is Data 1";}
    else {alert('Unprecedented failure. Please reload the page and report   the bug to me.');}
    function testJS() {
    var b = document.getElementById('goalPage').value,
    url = 'file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Coding%20Data%20Files/data1.html?name=load' + encodeURIComponent(b);

    document.location.href = url;
    }
    </script>
```

On my second page, this is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    <h1>w</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="goalPage"></p>
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
    var url = document.location.href,
    params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
    data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
     tmp = params[i].split('=');
     data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById('goalPage').innerHTML = data.load;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I used many other forum answers to try to get a working solution, however I could not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What data you want to transfer. Where is your paragraph?

Comment: what you need is AJAX, this allows you to pass data between pages, the simplest way to setup an AJAX request is using jQuery's AJAX method, check out this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/

Comment: What paragraph do you want to transfer?

Comment: The paragraph I want to transfer is the one with the id "goalPage"